# Improper integrals, one-sided limits and trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int \limits _{-1}^1\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

In my attempt I have

$$\int \limits _{-1}^0\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\int \limits _0^1\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\lim\limits _{a\rightarrow -1^+}-2\sin ^{-1}a +\lim\limits _{b\rightarrow 1^-}2\sin ^{-1}b=\pi +\pi$$

This solution is the same as the one in the textbook I am using.

In the first term, I have $\pi$ when I take $\lim\limits _{a\rightarrow -1^+}-2\sin ^{-1}a=-2\frac{-\pi}{2}$

I don't understand why $\lim\limits _{a\rightarrow -1^+}-2\sin ^{-1}a=-2\frac{3\pi}{2}$ is wrong since $\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2})=-1$

I think that it has something to do with the one sided limit but I really can't figure it out.

Comment: $\arcsin$ is the inverse function of $\sin$ on the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So $\arcsin(-1)=-\pi/2$ and not $3\pi/2$.

Comment: Thank you TheSilverDoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [the arcsine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) is continuous on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ and it is odd, i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Therefore 
$$\lim_{x\to -1^+}\arcsin(x)=\arcsin(-1)=-\arcsin(1)=-\frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Hence, since $D(\arcsin(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ (there is an extra factor $2$ in your attempt), it follows that
$$\int \limits _{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}\arcsin(x)-\lim_{x\rightarrow -1^+}\arcsin(x)=\arcsin(1)-\arcsin(-1)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi.$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $\arcsin$ on the interior of its domain $[-1,1]$ is $x\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. From here it follows that
$$\arcsin x = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}, \quad \forall x \in \langle -1,1\rangle$$

and therefore by taking the limit it follows
$$\frac{\pi}2 = \arcsin 1 = \lim_{x\to 1^-} \arcsin x = \lim_{x\to 1^-}\int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
and similarly $$-\frac\pi2 = \arcsin(-1) = \int_0^{-1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
Now we conclude
$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} - \int_0^{-1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \frac{\pi}2  - \left(-\frac{\pi}2\right) = \pi$$